# How to get iterate JSON object and JSON array using JavaScript .forEach

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
var json = {"tsn": {
    "settings": 
        {"app_name": "TSN",  "version": "1.0"}, 
    "occurrences": 
        ["Party", "Music"]
    }
};
```

I really don't understand why I can't access its values like this:

```
json.tsn.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.settings.app_name);
    console.log(item.occurrences);
});
```

I get `json.tsn.forEach is not a function`.

Comment: because `forEach` is array method and `json.tsn` is an object not array

Comment: do you really need a loop? Or just do `console.log(json.tsn.settings.app_name)`?

Comment: Yes, I do need a loop because this is the output of an API which has a lot more data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forEach` is a method available for arrays; it does not exist for non-array objects.

In fact, you don't need to iterate for what you are doing. Just do this:

```
var item = json.tsn;
console.log(item.settings.app_name);
console.log(item.occurrences);
```

Alternatively, you can use `Object.keys` to get an array of keys, and then you can continue like this:

```
Object.keys(json.tsn).forEach(function(key){
    var item = json.tsn[key];
    console.log(item);
});
```

Or even `Object.entries` to get key/value pairs:

```
Object.entries(json.tsn).forEach(function([key, item]){
    console.log(key, item);
});
```

Comment: logs aren't going to work for both since  item is dependent on key

Comment: Right, I just replaced that with a simple log instead. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, as said in my comment above, I need to loop. I didn't knew about `object.keys`. My Javascript knowledge is very basic.

Answer (score 2):

The `forEach` method isn't part of [the `Object` specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

To iterate through enumerable properties of an object, you should use the `for...in` statement.

```js
var json = {
    "tsn": {
        "settings": {
            "app_name": "TSN",
            "version": "1.0"
        },
        "occurrences": ["Party", "Music"]
    }
};

for (var prop in json) {
    console.log(json[prop].settings.app_name);
    console.log(json[prop].occurrences);
}
```

See [`for...in` statement reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).